# How to cnvert userAccountControl to 0 or 1

Tags: c#, active-directory

I currently working with `AD` and I fetch data from AD and store to file. Since I don't need some status code, I am interested only to check If user account is `512`- Enable or `514` - Disable and convert to bool value. Here is my code

```
public static List<Korisnik> VratiKorisnike()
{
    List<Korisnik> lstADUsers = new List<Korisnik>();
    string sDomainName = "sasaos";
    string DomainPath = "LDAP://" + sDomainName;



    string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DesignSaoOsig1;  Integrated Security=True";
    string Query = "SELECT * FROM tblZaposleni_AD";
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, constring);
    adapter.Fill(table);

    string txt = "";
    string fileLoc = @"C:\output.txt";

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        string line = "";
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            line += "," + row[column.ColumnName].ToString();
        }
        txt += line.Substring(1);
    }
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fileLoc))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(txt);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Ok");

    DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath);
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);


    search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";

    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname"); // Username
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname"); // display name
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userAccountControl");  // isEnabled
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("pwdLastSet"); //passwordExpires



    DataTable resultsTable = new DataTable();
    resultsTable.Columns.Add("samaccountname");
    resultsTable.Columns.Add("displayname");
    resultsTable.Columns.Add("Neaktivan");
    resultsTable.Columns.Add("dontexpirepassword");

    SearchResult result;

    SearchResultCollection resultCol = search.FindAll();

    if (resultCol != null)
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < resultCol.Count; counter++)
        {
            string UserNameEmailString = string.Empty;

            result = resultCol[counter];

            if (result.Properties.Contains("samaccountname")
                && result.Properties.Contains("displayname"))
            {
                int userAccountControl = Convert.ToInt32(result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0]);
                string samAccountName = Convert.ToString(result.Properties["samAccountName"][0]);

                int isEnable;
                int Dont_Expire_Password;

                if (userAccountControl > 0)
                {
                    isEnable = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    isEnable = 1;
                }


                if ((userAccountControl & 65536) != 0)
                {
                    Dont_Expire_Password = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    Dont_Expire_Password = 0;
                }




                Korisnik korisnik = new Korisnik();
                korisnik.Username = (result.Properties["samaccountname"][0]).ToString();
                korisnik.DisplayName = result.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();
                korisnik.isEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0]);


                DataRow dr = resultsTable.NewRow();
                dr["samaccountname"] = korisnik.Username.ToString();
                dr["displayname"] = korisnik.DisplayName.ToString();
                dr["neaktivan"] = Math.Abs(isEnable);
                dr["dontexpirepassword"] = Dont_Expire_Password;

                resultsTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                lstADUsers.Add(korisnik);
            }
        }
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultCol, Formatting.Indented);
        var res = json;
        Console.WriteLine("Ispis uspjesno obavljen");
        Console.ReadLine();
        File.WriteAllText(fileLoc, json);
    }
    return lstADUsers;
}
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue I would be very thankfull
So fat what I try

```
if (userAccountControl == 512)
                        {
                            dr["neaktivan"] = "Account Enabled";
                        }
                        if (userAccountControl == 514)
                        {
                            dr["neaktivan"] = "Account Disabled";
                        }
```

Doesn't show in my `output.txt`  any result

```
{
    "Path": "LDAP://sarajevoosigura/CN=Aldin Smajović,OU=Sarajevo,OU=People,DC=sarajevoosiguranje,DC=ba",
    "Properties": {
      "displayname": [
        "John Smith"
      ],
      "useraccountcontrol": [
        514
      ],
      "samaccountname": [
        "jsmith"
      ],
      "adspath": [
        "LDAP://test/CN=JohnSmith,OU=New York,OU=People,DC=sasa,DC=ba"
      ],
      "pwdlastset": [
        132295140030347373
      ]
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think about the numbers `512` or `514`, since they aren't actually relevant to what you're trying to find. The [`userAccountControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-useraccountcontrol) attribute is a bit flag, meaning that each bit (`0` or `1`) in the binary value is a flag that means something (`1` is on and `0` is off). The decimal representation of all those bits could be all kinds of values. For example, the decimal value could be `512` or `514` or even `65538` (if the account is disabled and has "don't expire password"). So ignore the decimal value.

The second bit is the flag for "disabled". If the second bit is `1`, the account is disabled. That's what you want to find.

John's answer does work in finding that, but it's (slightly) overly complicated.

You're already doing a proper test for the "don't expire password" flag:

```
if ((userAccountControl & 65536) != 0)
```

`65536` is `10000000000000000` in binary. So that `if` statement is saying "if the 17th bit is set". You just need to do exactly the same thing for the 2nd bit to figure out if it's disabled:

```
if (userAccountControl & 2 != 0)
{
    isEnable = 1;
}
else
{
    isEnable = 0;
}
```

You can read more about the "Logical AND operator &" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-and-operator-